# Linux PDF to HTML + Image Map + jpeg image files

Tags: php, html, linux, pdf, jpeg

What I want is a way to parse a PDF file into HTML with the image map (the hyperlinks) and the images must be in jpg format.

I have a Magazine Reader and I need the images and the position, href and size of each hyperlink.

The solution needs to be to run into a linux server.

Any suggestions?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look to the [pdf2html project](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/) or [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX).

That needs some tweaks to convert png to jpg as well.

This is that simple as :

```
convert foo.png foo.jpg
```

with ImageMagick tools.

See the [README](ftp://atrey.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/pub/local/clock/pdf2html/pdf2html-1.4/README).

Comment: Very good! But I needed something like that: export PDF into PNG's and export the links as an image map like x=10,y=50,w=58,h=21 so I can put a button over this area.

Comment: I think you can pick up one of the 2 tools & tweak it a bit to fit your needs. Thanks to "upvote" answer if it was useful, and "accept" answer if it fit your needs.